# JavaScript loop through array, remove duplicates per one value, then push to new array with that value and one other

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, duplicates, indexof

I have an array of objects coming to my Vuejs front-end via api call and I am attempting to loop through, remove duplicates, then return a new array with unique "phases" and their associated "id's". The original array has several other key/values I do not need. I am also sorting them in order by the phase number. Here's my code:

```
salesPhases () {
  let phases = this.$store.state.addresses.salesPhases
  let uniquePhases = []
  for (let i = 0; i < phases.length; i++) {
    if (uniquePhases.indexOf(phases[i].phase_number) === -1) {
      uniquePhases.push(phases[i].phase_number)
    }
  }
  return uniquePhases.sort((a, b) => {
    return a - b
  })
}
```

The above code works for everything I need, minus including the `id`. Here's my attempt at doing that, which then negates the unique phases condition.

```
uniquePhases.push([phases[i].phase_number, phases[i].id])
```

The sort still works, but it is then sorting one big single-dimensional array. The array of phases looks something like this:

```
{ "data": [
    {
        "id": "94e224af-135f-af31-3619-535acfae9930",
        "street_address1": "407 48TH ST E",
        "street_address2": null,
        "phase": "101",
        "sales_rep": "164",
        "id": "abd90d6b-28a8-2be6-d6c1-abd9007aef38",
        "name": "48TH ST E",
        "block_minimum": 400,
        "block_maximum": 498,
        "side": 2
    },
    {
        "id": "94e224af-135f-af31-3619-535acfae9930",
        "street_address1": "407 48TH ST E",
        "street_address2": null,
        "phase": "101",
        "sales_rep": "164",
        "id": "abd90d6b-28a8-2be6-d6c1-abd9007aef38",
        "name": "48TH ST E",
        "block_minimum": 401,
        "block_maximum": 499,
        "side": 1
    }
]
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of what phases contain??

Comment: Added to the main post ^^^

Comment: are you sure you want to store your data in an array such as [phase_number, id]? My guess is that it would be better to push({phase_number: phases[i].phase_number, id: phases[i].id})

Comment: That's not valid json... you have two "id" attributes.

Comment: That's not it, I just changed the lines here. They have different keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the array to get only unique, using a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), then [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the items into new objects that contain only the `id` and the `phase_number`, and then [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) by the `phase_number`:

```
salesPhases () {
  const uSet = new Set()
  return this.$store.state.addresses.salesPhases
    .filter(({ phase_number }) => uSet.has(phase_number) ? false : uSet.add(phase_number)) // get uniques by phase_number
    .map(({ id, phase_number }) => ({ id, phase_number })) // get an object with the id and the phase_number
    .sort((a, b) => a.phase_number - b.phase_number) // sort by phase_number
}
```

You can also use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), and then spread the [`Map.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values) iterator to an array

```
salesPhases () {
  return [...this.$store.state.addresses.salesPhases
    .reduce((m, { id, phase_number }) => 
      m.has(phase_number) ? m : m.set(phase_number, { id, phase_number }), new Map()) // set to map, if phase_number key doesn't exist
    .values()] // convert the Map values to an array
    .sort((a, b) => a.phase_number - b.phase_number) // sort by phase_number
}
```

Comment: I think since Set will be unique anyway, the .has() check isn't necessary, but perhaps the ES6 Map obj might be more suitable.

Comment: I'm using the Set to check if an id already exists when filtering the array. I'm not returning the Set as the result.

Comment: That's awesome! Thanks so much. I added some keys as well, but this is great

Comment: @MattLarson - welcome :) I've added another solution that uses Map and reduce.

Comment: So slick. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to update your code to push the entire phase object, rather than just the phase number, and then use the Array `find` method instead of `indexOf`, to check if a phase with the given number is found.

Try this:

```
salesPhases () {
  let phases = this.$store.state.addresses.salesPhases
  let uniquePhases = []
  for (let i = 0; i < phases.length; i++) {
    if (!uniquePhases.find(x => x.phase_number === phases[i].phase_number)) {
      uniquePhases.push(phases[i])
    }
  }
  return uniquePhases.sort((a, b) => {
    return a.phase_number - b.phase_number
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would leverage lodash for this: https://lodash.com/docs#sortedUniqBy

```
salesPhases () {
  return _.sortedUniqBy(this.$store.state.addresses.salesPhases, 
    phase => phase.phase_number)
}
```